# I was usiing Ubuntu 23.04 and the screen resolution changed from 1929x1080 to 1024x768

Tags: display, display-resolution

Using Ubuntu 23.04 the screen resolution changed from 1920x1080 to 1024x768 for no apparent reason.  It went back to 1920x1080 for a short time but  1024x786 returned when I rebooted it.I then tried reinstalling the operating system with Ubuntu 22.04 but the problem persists. In "settings" the 1920x768 resolution is not even shown. I am using a Dell Optiplex 780 with a Samsung SyncMaster 2333. The connection is VGA I have tried reconnecting it but to no avail. I have also tried the xrandr command in the terminal, but the higher res. is not shown there either. Hardware problem?

Comment: I just had a similar experience on Ubuntu 23.04 on an X230 (built-in Intel graphics). My external monitor is also a Dell. After a routine update, my external monitor became restricted to 1024x768. I'm using Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xorg or wayland? you can check by executing the following command:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If you are using xorg you can permanently change the resolution settings in /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. For more information please visit [blogspot](https://rolling-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-permanently-change-screen.html)

As for wayland, i don't think this issue was reported but if you are using wayland try switching to xorg if possible by either uncommenting the line `#WaylandEnable=false` at config or by logging into xorg from the lock screen